# Update method doesn't save to database in Grails

Tags: java, grails, orm, grails-orm, grails3

I'm trying to write custom a custom controller that would allow me to handle tables with composite keys in Grails 3.3.8. One such table that I have is called `AliasFrequencyDict` and so I created a method like this in the controller:

```
@Transactional
def update(AliasFrequencyDict aliasFrequencyDict) {

    aliasFrequencyDict = AliasFrequencyDict.get( new AliasFrequencyDict(params) )

    if (aliasFrequencyDict == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    try {
        aliasFrequencyDict.save(insert: false, flush: true, failOnError: true)
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        respond aliasFrequencyDict.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'aliasFrequencyDict.label', default: 'AliasFrequencyDict'), aliasFrequencyDict.getPK()])
            redirect(action: 'show', params: params)
        }
        '*'{ respond aliasFrequencyDict, [status: OK] }
    }
}
```

This seems like it should work - when I change something in the edit view and submit, I am correctly redirected to the `show` action, I get the flash message informing about successful update, the URL is `http://localhost:8080/aliasFrequencyDict/show?_method=PUT&version=&frequency=0&unit=Q&description=abc123&lang=PL`, and yet nothing changes in the record in the database itself. Why is that so? What may be wrong here?

Comment: Is your project available on github? Useful to see other things going on here such as `getPK()`

Comment: @MikeW - it's not and regretfully I don't think it can be as I'm doing this in a corporate environment so I don't think I'm allowed to show it in its entirety :( As for the problem here, though, adding a line `aliasFrequencyDict.properties = params` seems to have solved the problem!

Comment: I would expect you to get a 404 there because I don't think `AliasFrequencyDict.get( new AliasFrequencyDict(params) )` is ever going to find a matching record.  Maybe there is something in `AliasFrequencyDict` that would make that make more sense but at a glance I am not sure what the intent there is.

Comment: My previous comment assumes that your `notFound()` method returns a 404 of course.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - but that wasn't resulting in a 404, quite the contrary - a "successfully updated" message. Turns out the culprit was me not writing the params to the properties explicitly, like mentioned above. The `.get()` method way of looking for a record is based on this entry in the docs: http://docs.grails.org/3.0.2/guide/GORM.html#compositePrimaryKeys (as I mentioned, I'm using composite primary key here)

Comment: I had overlooked the composite key.  Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

OK, turned out the issue was simpler than it looked like - writing the params to the properties explicitly before saving was enough to fix it! So we simply do this:

```
...
if (aliasFrequencyDict == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

aliasFrequencyDict.properties = params /* <===== here! */

try {
    aliasFrequencyDict.save(insert: false, flush: true)
...
```

...and it works!